# Apache Axis WSDL2Java error - Missing <soap:fault> element

Tags: wsdl2java, soapfault

We are integrating a third party SOAP web services in our application. The WSDL is used with SOAPUI tool, where sample requests and responses worked fine.

When we try to integrate with apache Axis 1.3, where we tried WSDL2JAVA with the WSDL. We received the following error

java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing  element inFault "serviceFault" in operation "serviceFault", in binding saveRegistration
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.faultsFromSOAPFault(SymbolTable.java:2858)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateBindings(SymbolTable.java:2549)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Anyone already faced this issue and solved?

Answer (score 16):

I believe that there is a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2614) open for this one.

Description:

*When you have a soap 1.2 binding with soap fault, the fault element is not correctly extracted, resulting in error*

```
 ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "..." in operation "...", in binding ...
```

Their temporary recommendation is adding a line of code and recompiling Axis1...  Nahh.

Personally, I've just downloaded the wsdl file (it's an Axis 2 service and I have an Axis 1.5 client) and edited the namespace for all of the following lines from:

```
     <wsdl:fault name="Exception">
        <soap12:fault use="literal" name="Exception"/>
     </wsdl:fault>
```

to:

```
     <wsdl:fault name="Exception">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="Exception"/>
     </wsdl:fault>
```

As suggested [here](http://old.nabble.com/Re:-Fault-in-parsing-web-service-p14314253.html).

Upgrading to Axis2, however, is the best long term solution.  After resolving this issue, I have found yet more errors in the code that WSDL2JAVA has generated.

Comment: Thanks. Following worked for me
`<wsdl:fault name="Exception">
      <soap11:fault use="literal" name="Exception"/>
</wsdl:fault>`

Comment: This way it gives a classCastException as it states that cannot cast Throwable to this exception

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing XML namespace as below:

Change this

> xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/**soap12**/"

to

> xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/**soap**/"

only **12** at the end is removed.